How to export all types and vars in a single line?
I have the following code:
export * as command from "./src/lib/command";
export type * as Command from "./src/lib/command";

I'm wondering if I can use a syntax similar to this:
import { command, type Command } from "zap";

So ideally, I would like to do this:
export { * as command, type * as Command } from "./src/lib/command";

Is it possible?
Just curious is all.

TypeScript does not support exporting both types and values in a single export statement. You must use separate statements to achieve this.
You will have to use 2 lines like this:
// Export all values
export * as command from "./src/lib/command";

// Export all types
export type * from "./src/lib/command";


It's not possible, and your import example doesn't match what you want to do with aggregating export.
When we import { command, type Command } from "zap";, we expect the following from the module zap:
export const command = ...;
export type Command = ...;

There could be other exports but we won't import them. We get the following effect from the other side:
command = ...; // equals to command from zap
type Command = ...; // equals to Command from zap

That's different from using * star import. If we import * as command from "zap"; we get something different:
command = {
  command: ..., // equals to command from zap
  ... // everything else exported from zap
};

You want to have export { * as command, type * as Command } from "./src/lib/command"; but import { * as command } "./src/lib/command"; isn't valid syntax based on MDN. The star needs to be outside of curly bracket and it's called "namespace import".
One more thing. export * as command from "./src/lib/command"; already includes all the type definitions. It's a superset of export type * as Command from "./src/lib/command";. export * as command from "./src/lib/command"; can already do everything in a single line, if you don't need to have a separated Command namespace for type definitions.
